# Iterating over a list of strings that may be of length 1

Tags: python, list

Let's say I generate a list of strings:

```
def printList(list)
    for i in list:
        print(i)

string = 'hello,world,!'
strings = string.split(',')
printList(strings)
```

This works fine. However, if the string is only one element long, or I want to call printList with a type that is not iterable, then this falls apart. Consider the following (more relevant) example:

```
my_list=[]
def add_items_filtered(items)
    for item in items:
        if item > 5: #arbitrary filter
            my_list.append(item)

add_items_filtered([4,5,6,7]) #this works fine
add_items_filtered(6) #this fails
```

The issue here is that the item I sent is not "iterable". I can work around this with:

```
if not isinstance(items, list):
    items=[items]
```

But this seems like a hack. Is the only real way to do this by forcing the caller of this function to send me in a list? It seems counterintuitive to be roadblocked by such a simple issue.

Comment: well what is the expected return value of the function if you give it something thats not a list. like `add_items_filtered(some_non_iterable)` what would you expect the function to return in such a situation?

Comment: No, this is not a hack. In fact, this is how the type system works in most of the programming languages.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Like, in what context would you use the function? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832) because it doesn't really make sense for a function that works on a vector (list) to accept a scalar (int). Maybe you want to use [`*args`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) instead?

Comment: try-except is also another solution.

Comment: The intent of this function is to add whatever is passed in into a list (after applying a filter). I would like the caller to be able to dump in a list of objects to add, instead of having to itself loop and sequentially call the add function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a workaround, use

```
def add_items_filtered(*items):
```

Then you can pass arguments like

```
add_items_filtered(4,5,6,7)
add_items_filtered(6)
```

Otherwise, you'll have to check types, and there is nothing wrong with looping over a list of one element.

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with looping over a list of one elemet". Python throws type errors because the element that was passed in is not iterable. It's trying to iterate the item instead of the implicit list - which requires the type check

Comment: @BrydonGibson That's not what I was referring to. As the error says, you don't have a list. I was only referring to the fact that you could have `for x in range(1)`

Comment: Understood - that makes sense, as someone who stays at the lower levels, it's hard to tell what python will implicitly do for you, and what it won't